# removing a class from a jquerymobile page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a problem with jQuery Mobile. I have a `hideOnInit` class on a page.
like this:

```
<div data-role='page' id='hi' class='hideOnInit'>
```

on a button click i want to remove the `class='hideOnInit'`.

I have tried

```
$('#idOfPage').removeClass('hideOnInit');
```

and without the . before `hideOnInit`, but it isn't working.
could anyone help?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have to give `.` in `removeClass` with class name. Remove dot from class in parameter passed to removeClass.

You have div with `id = hi` but you are removing class from `id = idOfPage`

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/HrwEK/)

Change

```
$('#idOfPage').removeClass('.hideOnInit');
```

To

```
$('#idOfPage').removeClass('hideOnInit');
```

Change

```
<div data-role='page' id='hi' class='hideOnInit'>
```

To

```
<div data-role='page' id='idOfPage' class='hideOnInit'>
```

Comment: I think you are using wrong id eighter assign  idOfPage to your div id or use hi in jquery selector.

Answer (score 1):

ClassName should be used inside the removeClass method i.e without . (.hideOnInit)

```
$('#idOfPage').removeClass('hideOnInit');
```

Thanks

Comment: i have tried that but it isn't working. that's why i am posting this question.